# Which is better in Spark-SQL full load or Incremental load

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Hi I just need a small suggestion.

In my project they are converting all the Teradata queries to (Hive DB)Dataframes-pyspark/Spark-SQL.

Majority of the teradata queries are in truncate and load basis.

**For eg**

Say there are 10000 records in Table A

Table A gets data from another source on daily basis say Table M.

Each day we are getting only 5 to 6 new records.

Currently on daily basis we are truncating all the data from Table A and doing a full load from Table M.

Table M contains a update_timestamp column so incremental load is very much possible, also the table contains only primitive transactional datatypes.

**Using Spark-SQL which is the better way to write a query should I do Incremental load or Full-load like in Teradata?**

Comment: There is no reason to do a full load every time based on the scenario you have provided. If you wanted to do update else insert operations on hive DB, you need to have ACID enabled on hive, otherwise you have to do a full load every time. If you wanted to perform only inserts on Hive, then there is no reason to do full load.

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/9803143/sc0rpion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do incremental load to your table on daily basis keeping in mind update_timestamp column , please let me know if you need more details on this.

Comment: More details would surely increase your chances for upvotes. You decide. ;-)

Comment: Create one function to read last load date from Table A and accordingly fetch new data from Table M, in your case update_timestamp column.Finally keep track of this last loaded date on one of the audit or temp table to fetch fresh data next time.

Comment: Thanks for the additioal details. Please [edit] them into the answer itself.